# Do I have to give attribution to SO when using my own content elsewhere?

Tags: discussion, licensing, creative-commons

Content on SE sites is licensed under [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

If I write a question/answer on your sites, do I still have copyright of the text I entered or does SE now hold all copyright to it? Can I put an answer I wrote on my blog without meeting any of the attribution requirements?

I'm not intending to do so; I am just trying to learn about how the license works better.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> do I still have copyright of the text I entered? ... IE, can I put an answer I wrote on my blog without meeting any of the attribution requirements?

Yes and yes. All you did by publishing it under CC-Wiki was grant SE the  non-exclusive, irrevocable right to publish the text under the license's terms. Meaning that legally, you can't take it *back* from SE. But you are still the owner and copyright holder of what you wrote.

You can re-publish the text under any terms you wish - you could even put it into a book and sell it. That republication will have no connection to Stack Overflow and the CC-Wiki license.

However, while the *book* will of course be protected and can't be freely copied, the text you published on SO remains freely usable under the terms of the CC-Wiki license.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Can SE put my content in say a book and publish it without attribution to me theoretically?

Comment: @Tom no. They are bound by the terms of the CC-Wiki license, so they have to give proper attribution. They *can* put it into a book and sell it as long as they attribute it to you. Everybody else can also put it into a  book and sell it, but they have 1.) to attribute it to you *and* 2.) to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tom you're welcome! I had great fun composing the accompanying scientific illustration. :)

Comment: Can I sell my account details and hence transfer my attribution to someone else...? ;-)

Comment: @Pekka웃 beautiful picture, you have missed your calling ;) +1 great answer

Comment: I'd point out that search engines might dock you for exact duplicate text from other resources, so you're better off having *one* original source and blockquoting it everywhere else to emphasize that fact for SEO.