# write article on faq form

Tags: discussion, answers

I saw some answers that are excessively long.

1. [How should a model be structured in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc/5864000#5864000)
2. [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)
3. [Managing CSS Explosion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253110/managing-css-explosion/2253189#2253189)
4. [Managing CSS Explosion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4750313/1914752)
5. [Understanding Python decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators#1594484)

These are more like articles than answers. Isn't it appropriate to write an article here? Why not ask them to write in their blog or website?

Comment: Related: [Should SO host howto-style writeups after all?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104473)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because some topics require more explanation?

We want answers, good answers, to be posted on the site, not on some external blog that may or may not still exist in a years time.

Comment: You could argue though - if you want to be cynical - that it might actually be safer to have them on your own blog than on Stack Overflow: who knows whether the questions eventually get deleted because they are too broad, sending the answers down the drain unless somebody notices.

Comment: @Pekka: The author of the post is free to re-post it on their own blog, of course. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If they want to make sure their answers stick around, the authors may indeed want to store them somewhere safe, away from Stack Overflow. Many of those questions are so broad they might well get closed and deleted one day. Unless somebody is there to notice, to understand what happened, and to raise a mod flag for undeletion and preservation, the answers will simply be gone. (Needless to say I think that's a pretty sad state of affairs.)

In case it is unclear to anyone - it is perfectly fine to re-post content you write on Stack Overflow on your own blog or whatever! You keep the full copyright for your contributions and can do whatever you want with them; the CC license merely gives the community the right to use them under certain conditions.

Here's a [scientific infographic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123501/by-posting-a-selection-of-previously-written-text-here-are-we-waiving-our-copyr/123507#123507) explaining how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the titles of those questions. They are rather large topics to start with. Especially the ones with "managing" and "understanding".

There is nothing wrong with a long answer if the question needs it. As long as all of the information in the answer is relevant to the problem there is no problem.