# Can I use my own answer on my web site without attribution?

Tags: discussion, licensing, attribution

Upon answering a question on Stack Overflow, say I wanted to use my own answer in a blog post (or something similar) on my own personal site. Knowing that the Stack Exchange's content is [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) licensed and [requires attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), how does that translate when I am the author reusing my content on my own site?

To take it a step further: If I have an answer to a posted question published elsewhere, let's say to my own personal site again to avoid licensing confusion, that I feel applies to a question being asked on Stack Overflow and I copy paste it as an answer, who retains that license? Would I have to retroactively attribute Stack Overflow?

Comment: In my opinion you give new licence to your text, posting it here, but original licence stays intact. But I'm now a lawyer.

Comment: But if we borrow a quote from documentation or any other site, which may or may not be under a CC licence, we just link back. What if the answer I posted was on my website first? Then my SO answer should link back to my own website.

Comment: @notPekka Thank you, I missed that in my searching.

Comment: That one is easy to miss because of its generic title. Yours is much better. I think I'll edit the other question into a similar form

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use your own answer in any way you want, without attributing SO.

You are the copyright holder; you gave an irrevocable license to use the content to Stack Overflow, but you can give away the same content in any other way  you choose (free, commercial, restricted....).

See the highly scientific infographic from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123501):

[image]

Comment: My head does radiate when I write answers.  How could you have known???