# Can I claim on my blog that I wrote the SE answer, although the linked email accounts are different?

Tags: support, licensing, attribution

I want to reproduce the content of my SE answer on my blog elsewhere. I will follow the two rules of attribution and license linking. On my blog, I also want to mention that  I wrote the answer, by saying "My answer at SE..." . (Well, I indeed wrote the answer!) . But the email account linked to SE and one linked to my blog are different, though both are mine. In other words, there is no way to establish (for a onlooking lawyer) that it's indeed me, except for my statement of it. 
Is this okay ?

p.s. I have seen the following answers. They don't mention about the genuine "claiming" part.

[Can I use my own answer on my web site without attribution?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194612/307714)

["Attribution Required" misses requirement to reference the license](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225486)

[A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177)

Comment: I can't see this as being a issue, a lot of people have multiple email accounts that they use for different things and it shouldn't be hard to prove that you own both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You own and hold the copyright the content you write, it is only *licensed* to Stack Exchange, so as long as it is your content you can reproduce or do whatever you like with it, *without* attribution (although there's certainly nothing wrong with attributing it to your Stack Exchange account).

The only case in which you'd likely need to prove it was your content was if someone issued a DMCA takedown notice. Since you own the content that is unlikely to happen... and if it does, I'm sure you could prove to Stack Exchange that you own the content by contacting them through the email linked to your Stack Exchange account.

Comment: N.B., only the holder of the copyright can issue a takedown request, so this hypothetical interloper would not just be claiming that the content was _not_ OP's, they would be claiming it _was theirs_.

Comment: @Josh sure, which makes it all the more unlikely and hopefully easier to disprove